# How to pass an input string into a ViewComponent?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, .net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

Using **Core 3.1** and **Razor Pages**

I trying to undertake the simple task of passing a search string into a ViewComponent and invoke the results.

I have encountered two issue I cannot find help with:

1. How to pass the input search string to the view component?
2. How to invoke the view component when the search button is clicked?

**_Layout Page**

```
<input id="txt" type="text" />
<button type="submit">Search</button>

@await Component.InvokeAsync("Search", new { search = "" }) 
//Should equal input string
```

I am new to core so any nudges in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

View component is populated on server side and then return to your client for rendering, so you can't directly pass client side input value into view component . In your scenario , when clicking search button , you can use Ajax to call server side method to load the view component and pass the input value :

---

**Index.cshtml**

```
<input id="txt" type="text" />
<button onclick="loadcomponents()">Search</button>

<div id="viewcomponent"></div>

@section Scripts{ 
    <script>
        function loadcomponents() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/?handler=Filter',
                data: {
                    id: $("#txt").val()
                }
            })
                .done(function (result) {
                    $("#viewcomponent").html(result);
                });
        }
    </script>

}
```

**Index.cshtml.cs**

```
public IActionResult OnGetFilter(string id)
{
     return ViewComponent("Users", new { id = id });
}
```

**UsersViewComponent.cs**

```
public class UsersViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    private IUserService _userService;
    public UsersViewComponent(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(string id)
    {
        var users = await _userService.GetUsersAsync();
        return View(users);
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be the correct marked answer. But only with 1 change, the id should also be passed in the paramter of the service method to get the particular data.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: Oh, you edited the razor tag in after I posted my answer. Well, my answer is only valid for ASP.NET Core MVC.

---

I assume that your **controller** looks something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new IndexVM();
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(IndexVM model)
{
    // you can do something with the parameters from the models here, or some other stuff
    return View(model);
}
```

Your **ViewModel** can look like this:

```
public class IndexVM
{
    public string SearchTerm {get;set;}
}
```

Your **View** where you use your ViewComponent:

```
@model IndexVM

// <form tag ...
<input asp-for="SearchTerm" />
<button type="submit">Search</button>
@await Component.InvokeAsync(nameof(Search), Model)
```

**ViewComponent**:

```
public class Search : ViewComponent
{
    public IViewComponentResult Invoke(IndexVM indexVM)
    {
        // Do something with indexVM.SearchTerm
    }
}
```

**View of ViewComponent**:

```
@model IndexVM
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks for offering your time. I should have mentioned that I am using Razor Pages for this. My html and ViewComponet are invoked in a _Layout page which has no associated Controller. I am not sure where I can write the necessary code without having an associated code page. If this was on a view page I think I would be ok.